# ¿Es de "buena práctica" usar una funcion boolean o int como modificadora en Java?

Tags: java, buenas-prácticas, booleano

Estoy iniciando en la programación y quería saber si es de "buena práctica" usar una función de tipo BOOLEAN o INT  como "modificadora", para saber si se ejecuto correctamente dicho metodo?

Por si no me explico... he aquí un ejemplo en Java:

```
[...]
 public boolean agregarAuto(ObjetoAuto auto){
   [CODIGO QUE AGREGUE EL OBJETO AUTO A UNA LISTA](y si el auto se agrega a la lista correctamente 
   devuelve TRUE, pero si no por X motivo devuelve FALSE)
 }
[...]
```

¿o es conveniente y/o de buena práctica pasar una variable auxiliar para que devuelva el resultado?

Comment: Todo es dependiendo de tu gusto, y que instrucción vaya a cumplir tú función. Si tú necesitas que tú función te tenga que dar una respuesta lógica, si se cumplió o no, ya es a criterio tuyo. Pero hay que tener cuidado en no atascarte mucho en funciones booleanas, como ya dije es a gusto del programador puede que dicha función le resulte mejor que usar una que no le genere una respuestal "false" o "true".

Comment: ahí le hice una aclaración al ejemplo que propuse, pero creo que la respuesta no cambiaría... Gracias por responder!

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta está basada en las opiniones de cada desarrollador.  Personalmente prefiero hacer uso de [`throw`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) para indicar una condición de error que devolver `true` o `false`.

Comment: Es que además es una pregunta amplia (borrar un fichero que no existe puede no ser un error, si nos estamos asegurando de que no exista, pero no poder escribir en un fichero por que no existe sí)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En snippet mencionas que devuelves `falso` si cualquier cosa falla, eso me hace pensar, por motivos de depuración o de información para el usuario ¿no te interesa saber por qué falló?. Esta es una pregunta está un poco basada en opiniones. Por ejemplo, Supongamos que tu método inserta en una base de datos y `ObjetoAuto` tiene un valor incorrecto (un campo de texto mas grande que el admitido), o que la conexión con la DB se haya interrumpido, ahí tienes dos motivos distintos por los cuales puede fallar; tu método solo regresaría `false` sin tú saber porque falló, en cambio con un `int` podrías devolver un código de error que te serviría para depurar.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no deberías utilizar una variable `int` o `boolean` más que para responder el valor de una propiedad numérica o para "preguntar" a tu objeto si cumple con alguna condición (generalmente los getters the propiedades boolean tienen el prefijo `is`). Si lo que deseas es verificar que algo en tu proceso del negocio ha fallado, no deberías depender de la respuesta de un método sino deberías lanzar una excepción no chequeada (unchecked exception). E.G.

```
public void addCar(final Car car) {
  // tu lógica de negocio por acá
  // suponiendo que tienes una llamada a una base de datos con checked exception
  try {
    db.save(car);
  } catch(ACheckedException exception) {
    throw new UncheckedException(exception);
  }
}
```

De manera que el cliente realmente fallará la ejecución si tu método falla. Ahora si realmente necesitas enviar una excepción chequeada, pues lo indicas en la firma de tu método:

```
public void addCar(final Car car) throws ACheckedException {
}
```

De este modo, el cliente de tu método se verá obligado a manejar el error si o si. Espero que sea de ayuda la respuesta.